# looking for an other way to get the last post ID from wpdb

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get the last post ID from $wpdb. For some reason `$wpdb->insert_id` only returns zero. What would be another way to get the last post ID?

Comment: `$wpdb->insert_id` is only if you inserted something (not necessarily a post) via `$wpdb`. What are you trying to get, just the latest post? `get_posts()` should suffice in that case.

Comment: get_posts only returns the first post from wp_posts in my case. Do you think this has to do with the fact that WooCommerce created all the following posts in this table?

Comment: probably. the question is: what are you trying to return?

Comment: @ kennypu: I try to return the last post inserted. For some reason get_posts only returns me an array with one post (the first one), although there are many more...

Answer (score 0):

The insert_id is a property, not a method. Try it without the () .

Comment: thx. tried it withough (). only returns zero although there are many posts.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress specifies a `get_the_ID()` ([Docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID)) function within ["The Loop"](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) which is typically used to iterate through posts outside of the WP site. In this case we just run through it and break after the most recent post ID (first ID in array) is retrieved.

```
<?php
require_once("path/to/your/wp-config.php");
$wp->init();
query_posts(array('post__in' => $postarray ));
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $most_current_id = get_the_ID();
    if ($most_current_id){
        echo "Most recent Post ID: $current_id";
        break;
    }
endwhile;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

write the below sql query to get the last post id

$posts_table = $wpdb->prefix."posts";
    $first_post = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT  MAX(ID) FROM $posts_table WHERE  post_status = 'publish'",ARRAY_A);

$post_table return the last post..